# Why does Visible not work in view?

Tags: android, listview, layout, webview

Why does Visible not work in view?

[image]

My code works well. If I clicked on WebView, it is `setVisible(GONE);`.

If you click again, it is `estVisivle(VISIBLE)`;

Logically it should work, but doesn't work

Why?

http://snag.gy/AKUbW.jpg

```
class MyLinkWebView extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        layoutList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        SetAuthorText(msgView);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is not working(

Help me Somebody!!!.
This is code Button WORKING. But if the same thing be done in WebView OR ListVIew 
nothing will not work.What the hell!!?

```
        Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Code WebVieW

```
  private void SetAuthorText(boolean msgView) {
    positionText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.text);
    String text = positionText[indexAuthor];

    if (!msgView) text=text.substring(0,500)+"...<a href=\"#\">Читать  дальше</a>";

    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    String html="<html><head>\n" +
            "    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=no\" />\n" +
            "</head><body style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px;\">"+
            "<img align=\"left\"   src=\"file:///android_res/drawable/photo_1.png\"/><p><font size=-5>"+text+"</p>  </body></html>";
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}
```

Comment: Did you try setVisibility(View.INVISBLE) instead of setVisibility(View.GONE)

Comment: Maybe I'm not in that thread do?

Comment: @Vigneshearan.m, Yes I have tried everything and tried and tried and searched, and found, and put thought and wrote, and again was looking for, it does not work in WebView OR ListView, And in the button работает без проблем!

Comment: So I concluded that there WebView is no access in UI Activity.And he for some reason can't change the text during work....

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve? Do you want to hide listview when loading is complete?

Answer (score 2):

There's difference between `View.GONE` and `View.INVISIBLE`. `View.GONE` means that view is not visible and takes no space, so you can't click it. `View.INVISIBLE`is invisible but view still takes space and you can click it. So i suggest you to replace `GONE` with `INVISIBLE`.

Answer (score 0):

GONE is gone! you can't clock on it

Answer (score 0):

So thank you, but your answers were not correct, none, especially about GONE, so as not my first time programming and exactly the error was not due to this. The question, I wrote, "Maybe it's a bug?. In General, the error was there.

instead

```
<a href=\"#\"
```

it

```
<a href=\"mylink.com\"
```